# How to pass data from a child to another a child (nested in Home page) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling to figure out how to pass the **search term** from **ChildOne** to **ChildTwo** (which is nested in a page). I hope all the code I provided down below will make it clear. I tried to lift up the state to the App.js component but it didn't work or maybe I didn't do it correctly. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance :)

Child 1:

```js
const ChildOne = () => {
  const [searhTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  
  return(
    <InputContainer>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Find a recipe"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
       <SearchIcon />
    </InputContainer>
  )
}
```

Child 2:

```js
const ChildTwo = () => {
  
 // I want to pass the searchTerm to be used in a fetch request in this component 
  const apiURL = `'url' + {searchTerm}`;
  
  return(
    ...
  )
}
```

App.js

```js
function App(){

  return(
    <>
      <ChildOne/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      <Switch/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Home.js:

```js
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildTwo />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: 1. Define `searhTerm` state in the `App` component. 2. Change `<ChildOne/>` to `<ChildOne setSearch={setSearch} setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm}/>`. 3. Change `<Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>` to `<Route path="/" exact render={(routerProps) => <Home {...routerProps} searchTerm={searchTerm}/>}/>`

Comment: You can put the `searchterm` in Home and pass it to both `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`. When the value is updated in `ChildTwo` the update will reflect in Both components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is several way to do that...
I suggest you use Context Api.
if you don't want to use Context Api or State management

see this example

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sid-552f4?file=/src/Home.js)

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  RouterProps
} from "react-router-dom";
import ChildOne from "./ChildOne";
import Home from "./Home";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <ChildOne setValue={setValue} />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Home value={value} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked but I still have one question if you don't mind. What's the difference between: 
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/" exact>
       <Home value={value} />
     </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>

AND 

<Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} value={value} />
</Switch>
Since the first method worked but second didn't. Thanks in advance

Comment: well if you want to pass props to the component in Route you must do what I say or you can do this instead      <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            component={() => <Home value={value} />}
          ></Route>